# protractor cucumber: asynchronous method result shows as Pending Promise in step definition instead of actual data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using protractor cucumber successfully connected to MSSQL server. In Step definition trying to access result set but it shows `{(Pending Promise)}`.

Actually, I  want the result set data in step definition see below `("this.When('I query..'))` block to compare with UI page. 
However the result set data shows at the end of all step definitions.

In Step Definition called `dbConnect.getDBResult` method and this method behaves async.

**In Step Definition:**

```
<pre><code>
   var dbConnect = require(../db/abc.js);

   this.When(/^I query the Student table & compare result with student list page 
    of UI $/, function () {
         var sqlStr = "select * from Student";
         var rs =  dbConnect.getDBResult(sqlStr, function (err,recordset){
              console.log('Record Set ', recordset);
              /// Need the data for compare with UI page. 
          });
              console.log('Data ', rs);
    }


    (../db/abc.js) file as below    

    var sql  = require('mssql');

    var setupMSQL= function () {
    var config = {
    user:xxx
    password: 'zzzz',
    server: 'xxx.xx.xx.xx',
    options: {encrypt: true, database: 'DBNAME'}
    };


     this.getDBResult = function (sqlQry, callback) {
          sql.connect(config, function (err) {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            return request.query(sqlQry, callback);
      });
    }
    module.exports = new setupMSQL();       

    </pre></code>
```

So after calling `getDBResult()` method should get the result in step 
definition instead of at the end of all step definition.

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: recordset data should get in step definition but its failed due async call and the recordset data get at the end. Due to this issue can't compare UI v/s DB results in step definition.